# Change Alphabets keypad as secondary and make Numeric Keypad as Primary

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, mobile

Is there a way to make the numeric keypad as primary keypad and alphabets as secondary keypad on inputtype=text in particular HTML file?

The reason I need this: I have a list of input box where the user has to enter numbers and **occasionally user enters text** in a webbased mobile app.

It would be hard for the user to switch, the default alphabet keypad to numeric keypad and type a number > and then click on the next box > see's Alphabet keypand again switch to number keypad, he has to do the same for next input box's (it is practically hard for the user if we have 200 input's.

Comment: please post in your ideas.if any ??

Answer (score 0):

if you use `<input type="number">` the numeric keypad should appear.

Comment: But that will not allow the user to enter text occasionally... does it ?

Comment: you said you have several input boxes, some for text and some for numbers. just use <input type="text"> where the alphabet keypad should appear and <input type="number"> where the numeric keypad should appear.

Comment: Actually, imagine i have 500 input boxes, all of them are for both numbers and Alphabets, however, majority of the time, it is used for numbers.. occasionally the user will enter text on any of the boxes..

Comment: aha, now i get it. but unfortunately i don't know if there's a way to do this, sorry :/ maybe give `<input type="tel">` a try

Comment: The tel type is currently supported only in Safari 8, anything that supports all the browsers ?